# How to make couple of text box next to radio button once it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox

Below is my HTML page which shows three radio button currently -

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="tt1" value="Insert" /> Insert<br />
<input type="radio" name="tt2" value="Update" /> Update<br />
<input type="radio" name="tt3" value="Delete" /> Delete<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I am currently trying to do is -

- As soon as I click `Insert` radio button, I want to show two text box next to Insert radio button
- And as soon as I click `Update` radio button, I want to show again two text box next to Update radio button
- And as soon as I click `Delete` radio button, I want to show only one text box next to Delete radio button

And only one radio button will be active at a time.

How would I do this? Any JSFiddle example will be of great help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way, no jQuery or complex JavaScript, and detailed so that you know what's happening:

**Markup**:

```
<input type="radio" name="tt" value="Insert" onclick="doDisplay(this);"/> Insert
<span id="inserts" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</span>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tt" value="Update" onclick="doDisplay(this);"/> Update
<span id="updates" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</span>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tt" value="Delete" onclick="doDisplay(this);"/> Delete
<span id="delete" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" />
</span>
<br />
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function doDisplay(radio)
{
    switch (radio.value)
    {
        case "Insert":
            document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "Update":
            document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "Delete":
            document.getElementById("inserts").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("updates").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("delete").style.display = "inline";
            break;
    }
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/n3wCy/

A couple of things: Notice the names of the radio buttons is the same, that makes it so that you can select one in the group. If you do not want this, you need to uncheck/check the radio buttons with JavaScript. I show the textboxes based on the actual value of the radio buttons, you can make this so that is less verbose, for instance you can add id's to the radios.